# Catching cURL errors with PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

For my Laravel application, I use the Goutte package to crawl DOMs, which allows me to use guzzle settings.

```
$goutteClient = new Client();
$guzzleClient = new GuzzleClient(array(
    'timeout' => 15,
));
$goutteClient->setClient($guzzleClient);

$crawler = $goutteClient->request('GET', 'https://www.google.com/');
```

I'm currently using guzzle's `timeout` feature, which will return an error like this, for example, when the client times out:

> cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 1009 milliseconds with 0
>   bytes received (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Now this is cool and all, but I don't actually want it to return a cURL error and stop my program.

I'd prefer something like this:

```
if (guzzle client timed out) {
    do this
} else {
    do that
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Guzzle has its own error handling for requests.

Source: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#exceptions

Solution:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

...

try {
    $crawler = $goutteClient->request('GET', 'https://www.google.com');
    $crawlerError = false;
} catch (RequestException $e) {
    $crawlerError = true;
}


if ($crawlerError == true) {
    do the thing
} else {
   do the other thing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the inbuilt Laravel Exception class.

Solution:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Exception;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        try
        {
            $crawler = $goutteClient->request('GET', 'https://www.google.com');
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            logger()->error('Goutte client error ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works for me. Laravel HTTP client wrapped Guzzle and works well and handily but unfortunately it just does not catch connection failure without a server response. In some cases we do need to know if a thread is running or failed on the server therefore a ConnectionException should be regarded as one type of catch returns. For now guess we will have to write `try { //try code } cat (Exception $long_useless_error) {//not succeeded, do something}` to make our logic complete.  p.s do not forget to quote `use Exception;` on the top of your controller.